# Flutter dependency compatibility issue "syncfusion_flutter_pdf"

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem with the syncfusion_flutter_pdf dependencie.
When I flutter pub get with the latest version I get the following error:

**Because syncfusion_flutter_pdf> = 19.2.44-beta depends on crypto ^ 3.0.0 and uuid> = 2.0.0-rc1 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on crypto ^ 2.0.0, syncfusion_flutter_pdf> = 19.2.44-beta is incompatible with uuid> = 2.0.0-rc1 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0.
And because odoo_api 1.0.4 depends on uuid ^ 2.0.2 and no versions of odoo_api match> 1.0.4 <2.0.0, syncfusion_flutter_pdf> = 19.2.44-beta is incompatible with odoo_api ^ 1.0.4.
So, because isonor_app depends on both odoo_api ^ 1.0.4 and syncfusion_flutter_pdf ^ 19.2.60-beta, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because isonor_app depends on both odoo_api ^ 1.0.4 and syncfusion_flutter_pdf ^ 19.2.60-beta, version solving failed.)
exit code 1**

I tried to change the versions of uuid but it causes me more problems.
My pubspec is the following:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9    # Good, any 5.4.x version where x >= 0 works.
  shared_preferences:
  intl: ^0.17.0
  date_format: ^2.0.2
  odoo_api: ^1.0.4
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.3
  syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^19.2.60-beta
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/Logo_ISONOR_blanco.png"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
     - assets/images/
```

Removing the dependecie from syncfusion_flutter_pdf everything works fine. And I updated flutter to the latest version. I don't know how to make the dependencies work together :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do this `syncfusion_flutter_pdf: any`
this will give a compatible version to your application

Answer (score 0):

If you face this kind of incompatibility issue, you can simply remove the version from every library/packages. It will work fine in every case.